# Can I create separate bridges for every lxc user?

Tags: bridge, lxc

I have successfully created unprivileged lxc containers for one user on a system. All of those containers use the default `lxcbr0` bridge.

Now I want to allow other users on the system to create unprivileged lxc containers.

**How do I create more bridges, one for each of the users? And is it a good idea to do this?**

One reason for separate bridges is: keeping the ip-address range separate, so that one user can't hijack the ip addresses allocated to another user's lxc.

Comment: This seems to be possible. All I need is the /etc scripts to support creating a list of bridges (so that it can be managed easily). I have requested the feature in Ubuntu [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/lxc/+bug/1359224)

Comment: It might be time to move onto something more powerful to manage your containers, like libvirt, which will create as many bridges as you want.

Comment: @MichaelHampton The [Ubuntu serverguide](https://help.ubuntu.com/14.04/serverguide/lxc.html) says "Use of libvirt-lxc is not generally recommended due to a lack of Apparmor protection for libvirt-lxc containers.?" Just quoting; don't shoot the messenger.

Comment: Well, use of Ubuntu is not generally recommended either. :)